# Memory not freeing when allocated using ION memory technique?

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-leaks, linux-kernel

A strange thing is happening with my linux application where am using ION memory for ipc between user space and kernel space.

The purpose to use ION memory is because our SoC have a custom hardware decoder which uses ION memory (under its driver implementation) and I am making a decoder user space application. I have studied the ION memory from this [reference](https://lwn.net/Articles/480055/).

Everything works fine and perfectly, but when I runs the application in loop such that it never exit main() and keep on going on from start to finish, the ION memory doesn't released and keep on increasing as shown below using pmap.

```
pmap 1088
1088:   ./vdectest bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal_10sec.h264 1920 1080 out.yuv
00010000     20K r-x-- vdectest
00024000      4K rw--- vdectest
00025000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
40037000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
4006c000     96K r-x-- ld-2.21.so
40093000      4K r---- ld-2.21.so
40094000      4K rw--- ld-2.21.so
400ba000    100K r-x-- libgcc_s.so.1
400d3000     60K ----- libgcc_s.so.1
400e2000      4K rw--- libgcc_s.so.1
400e3000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
40123000      8K rw---   [ anon ]
401cb000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
40241000     64K r-x-- libpthread-2.21.so
40251000      4K r---- libpthread-2.21.so
40252000      4K rw--- libpthread-2.21.so
40253000      8K rw---   [ anon ]
4032f000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
403c4000    868K r-x-- libc-2.21.so
4049d000     60K ----- libc-2.21.so
404ac000      8K r---- libc-2.21.so
404ae000      4K rw--- libc-2.21.so
404af000     12K rw---   [ anon ]
404bd000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
404be000      4K -----   [ anon ]
404bf000   8188K rw---   [ anon ]
40d1e000      4K -----   [ anon ]
40d1f000   8188K rw---   [ anon ]
4151e000   2048K rw-s-   [ anon ]
417c0000   2048K rw-s-   [ anon ]
41a9c000   2048K rw-s-   [ anon ]
41d00000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
41d21000    892K -----   [ anon ]
41e00000      4K -----   [ anon ]
41e01000   8188K rw---   [ anon ]
42600000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
4297c000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
42cb8000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
43036000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
43386000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
43742000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
43b08000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
43e48000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
44226000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
44557000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
4494b000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
44d1f000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
45038000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
4539d000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
4576b000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
45a84000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
45f00000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
45f21000    892K -----   [ anon ]
46000000   8704K rw-s-   [ anon ]
be848000    132K rw---   [ stack ]
ffff0000      4K r-x--   [ anon ]
 total    92116K


pmap 1088
1088:   ./vdectest bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal_10sec.h264 1920 1080 out.yuv
00010000     20K r-x-- vdectest
00024000      4K rw--- vdectest
00025000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
40003000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
4006c000     96K r-x-- ld-2.21.so
40087000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
40093000      4K r---- ld-2.21.so
40094000      4K rw--- ld-2.21.so
400ba000    100K r-x-- libgcc_s.so.1
400d3000     60K ----- libgcc_s.so.1
400e2000      4K rw--- libgcc_s.so.1
40123000      8K rw---   [ anon ]
401cb000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
40241000     64K r-x-- libpthread-2.21.so
40251000      4K r---- libpthread-2.21.so
40252000      4K rw--- libpthread-2.21.so
40253000      8K rw---   [ anon ]
4032f000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
403c4000    868K r-x-- libc-2.21.so
4049d000     60K ----- libc-2.21.so
404ac000      8K r---- libc-2.21.so
404ae000      4K rw--- libc-2.21.so
404af000     12K rw---   [ anon ]
404bd000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
404be000      4K -----   [ anon ]
404bf000   8188K rw---   [ anon ]
40d1e000      4K -----   [ anon ]
40d1f000   8188K rw---   [ anon ]
4151e000   2048K rw-s-   [ anon ]
4178f000   2048K rw-s-   [ anon ]
41a29000   2048K rw-s-   [ anon ]
41d00000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
41d21000    892K -----   [ anon ]
41e00000      4K -----   [ anon ]
41e01000   8188K rw---   [ anon ]
42600000      4K -----   [ anon ]
42601000   8188K rw---   [ anon ]
42e00000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
43198000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
434b5000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
43805000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
43bf9000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
43f9f000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
442ea000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
44659000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
4496d000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
44d00000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
450e6000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
45459000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
45789000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
45b73000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
45f00000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
45f21000    892K -----   [ anon ]
46000000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
4633b000   3064K rw-s-   [ anon ]
46660000   8704K rw-s-   [ anon ]
be848000    132K rw---   [ stack ]
ffff0000      4K r-x--   [ anon ]
 total   100308K
```

One can see that total memory used by the process "vdectest"  is increased from **92116K** to **100308K** described above using pmap. This virtual memory size keeps on growing until it reaches actual physical memory size and then the process will exit with error ENOMEM "**cannot allocate memory**".

Comment: The first obvious thing to ask is: How are you releasing the memory?

Comment: @immibis I am allocating memory using ION_IOC_ALLOC and ION_IOC_MAP ioctls, then in user space am using mmap call to map. I am releasing memory using ION_IOC_FREE ioctl and then in user space using munmap call to un-map.

Comment: Without further knowledge: unmapping **after** freeing sounds like a very bad idea. See [ask], post a [mcve].

Comment: My bad with the sentence formation, I am un-mapping and then releasing ION memory using ION_IOC_FREE ioctl.